# MySQL database design for bigdata

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, bigdata

I'm not a database specialist, therefore I'm coming here for a little help.
I have planty of measured data and I want help myself with data manipulation. Here is my situation:
There are cca 10 stations, measuring every day. Everyday, one produces cca 3000 rows (with cca 15 columns) of data. Data have to be downloaded once a day from every station to the centralized server. That means cca 30 000 inserted rows into the database every day. (daily counts are mutable)

Now, I've already had data from a few past years, so for every station, I have a few milions of rows. There are also cca 20 "dead" stations - don't work anymore, but there are data from a few years.
Sum this all up and we'll get cca 50+ millions of rows, produced by 30 stations and cca 30 000 rows inserted every day. Looking ahead, let's assume 100 millions of rows in database.

My question is obvious - how would you suggest to store this data?
Measured values(columns) are only numbers (int, or double + datetime) - no text, or fulltext search, basically the only index I need is DATETIME.
Data will not be updated, nor deleted. I just need a fast select of a range of data (eg. from 1.1.2010 to 3.2.2010)

So as I wrote, I want to use MySQL because that's the database I know best. I've read, that it should easily handle this amount of data, but still, I appreciate any suggestion for this very situation.
Again:

- 10 stations, 3000 rows per day each => cca 30 000 inserts per day
- cca 40-50 millions of rows yet to be inserted from binary files
- DB is going to grow (100+ millions of rows)
- The only thing I need is to SELECT data as fast as possible.

As far as I know, MySQL should handle this amount of data. I also know, that my only index will be date and time in DATETIME type (should be faster then others, am I right?)
The thing I can't decide is, whether create one huge table with 50+ millions of rows (with station id), or create table for every station separately. Basically, I don't need to perform any JOIN on these stations. If I need to do time coincidence, I can just select the same range of time on stations. Are there any dis/advanteges on these approaches?

Can anyone confirm/decline my thoughts? Do you think, that there is a better solution? I appreciate any help or discussion.

Comment: I think he means "circa" which is Latin for "around" or "approximately".

Comment: 100 million rows though not small, is not considered "big data" nowadays ;)

Comment: It's pretty 'big data' for me :D
And yes, cca is approximately, sorry. The numbers are my estimation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL should be able to handle this pretty well.  Instead of indexing just your `DATETIME` column, I suggest you create two compound indexes, as follows:

```
(datetime, station)
(station, datetime)
```

Having both these indexes in place will help accelerate queries that choose date ranges and group by stations or vice versa. The first index will also serve the purpose that just indexing `datetime` will serve.

You have not told us what your typical query is. Nor have you told us whether you plan to age out old data. Your data is an obvious candidate for range partitioning (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-range.html) but we'd need more information to help you design a workable partitioning criterion.

**Edit** after reading your comments.

A couple of things to keep in mind as you build up this system.

First, Don't bother with partitions for now.

Second, I would get everything working with a single table. Don't split stuff by station or year. Get yourself the fastest disk storage system you can afford and a lot of RAM for your MySQL server and you should be fine.

Third, take some downtime once in a while to do `OPTIMIZE TABLE`; this will make sure your indexes are good.

Fourth, don't use `SELECT *` unless you know you need all the columns in the table. Why? Because

```
      SELECT datetime, station, temp, dewpoint
        FROM table
       WHERE datetime >= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 60 DAY)
       ORDER BY station, datetime
```

can be directly satisfied from sequential access to a compound covering index on

```
     (station, datetime, temp, dewpoint)
```

whereas

```
      SELECT *
        FROM table
       WHERE datetime >= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 60 DAY)
       ORDER BY station, datetime
```

needs to random-access your table. You should read up on compound covering indexes.

Fifth, avoid the use of functions with column names in your `WHERE` clauses. Don't say

```
      WHERE YEAR(datetime) >= 2003
```

or anything like that. MySQL can't use indexes for that kind of query. Instead say

```
      WHERE datetime >= '2003-01-01'
```

to allow the indexes to be exploited.

Comment: My typical query is `SELECT * FROM station1_data WHERE datetime BETWEEN`. If everything is one huge table, then `SELECT * FROM data WHERE datetime BETWEEN ... AND station_id=1`.
Old data should not be considered as old. They are here and are as useful as new. People are going to process the data and want everything available.
As I understand, you suggest one huge table with station_id, right?
Patitioning is interesting, I didn't know about that. Would it be helpful to do partitioning on station_id?